# What are the option for spring @Advice to communicate with some other service?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

We are using `Spring` with `Spring AOP`. For regular `Spring Bean/Service/Repository`  (i.e `@Service` and etc) the `@Autowired` annotation works well. But, it won't work out of the box for `@Advice` class.

### My question is:

What are the option for `@Advice` to communicate with another `@Service`?

## Thanks!

#### Some example

1. Search the `db` (using `JPA;Hibernate`) within the `advice`
2. Raise event in system, using `ApplicationEventPublisher`
3. Call some function defined in some X `service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put together a simple experiment app:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectAdviceHere {
}

@Service
public class FooService {
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

@Service
public class BarService {
    @InjectAdviceHere
    public void bar(){
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}


@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    private final FooService fooService;

    @Autowired
    public MyAspect(FooService fooService) {
        super();
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    @Before("@annotation(ann)")
    public void advize(InjectAdviceHere ann) {
        fooService.foo();
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class DemoApplication {

    private @Autowired BarService barService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void test(){
        barService.bar();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
foo
bar
```

As you can see, in Spring AOP aspects are treated just as any other beans and can have dependencies injected normally.

Comment: @Apokraplisa, very interesting, so you say the `Aspect` is not single tone? and can get the `dependencies`  with `injection?

Comment: well, it works! but isn't aspect should be a single tone?

Comment: No, in Spring AOP aspects are not required to be implemented as singletons. They are beans, which can (should?) be placed in Singleton scope (one instance per application context).

Comment: So this is a the different between `Aspect via proxy` and `Aspect by waving`